# Function to return custom post type titles from blog id 1

Tags: functions

I'm trying to create a function to retrieve all titles from a custom post type located on blog id=1.

I tried to use foreach but I cannot get it to work. The closest I have been was using this:

```
function getctas() {
    switch_to_blog(1);

        $args =  array(
            'post_type' => 'location_icons',
         );

        $ctas = new WP_Query($args);
        while ($ctas -> have_posts()) {
        $ctas -> the_post();
        $titles = get_the_title($post->ID);
        restore_current_blog();
        return $titles;
        }

}
```

The issue I'm facing with this is that the function is returning only 1 post title and not all as I intend to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's returning just 1 post title because everytime it reads a post it replaces the content of the var $titles with the title of the current post.

Try this, it will return an array with the post titles.

```php
function getctas() {

    $titles_array = array();
    switch_to_blog(1);

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'location_icons'
     );

    $ctas = new WP_Query( $args );
    while ( $ctas->have_posts()) {
        $ctas->the_post();
        array_push($titles_array, get_the_title() );
    }
    restore_current_blog();
    return $titles_array;
}
```

To add the ID you could do something like this:

- Create a temporary array to hold the informations you want
- Add the informations to the array
- And then push that information in to the output array.

```php
function getctas() {

    $titles_array = array();
    switch_to_blog(1);

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
    );

    $ctas = new WP_Query( $args );
    while ( $ctas->have_posts()) {
        $ctas->the_post();

    $temp_array               = array();
        $temp_array['post_id']    = get_the_ID();
        $temp_array['post_title'] = get_the_title();    

        array_push($titles_array, $temp_array );
    }
    restore_current_blog();
    return $titles_array;
}
```

Comment: Hi Marcos, thanks for your help. I have tried your proposed solution but instead of returning the titles it returns `Array`

Comment: Replace 'post_type' => 'post', with your post_type,             'post_type' => 'location_icons' I'll fix it. I have fixed the code, try it now.

Comment: I actually did that when I tried, but I get `Array`. Maybe because I'm using `<?php echo getctas(); ?>` on my test template?

Comment: Yes, I've returned you an array with all the post title, you can't echo an array, you could use a foreach or change the output of the function, instead of an array a string with the titles separated by comas, I don't know how you need it, but with the array you could change to whatever you want it.

Comment: I initially wanted to use this to populate a select on backend, and your code is working there. Thank You!!!
PS: If I'd want to add more things to that array, like ID for example, how will be the correct way to do?
Thanks Again Marcos!

Comment: @MarcosRodriguez Would you please take a look at this http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/147445/15574 I didn't want to put that in this same post to not confuse anyone. Thanks in advance!